# "Client Critical Interface eth0/2 is down or doesn't have any link-local address" while starting a service after the network is up

Tags: upstart

I'm trying to start an upstart job after making sure networking interfaces are up.

This is what I have now:

```
start on started network-interface INTERFACE=eth0
stop on runlevel [!2345]

pre-start script
    test -x /usr/sbin/dibbler-client || { stop; exit 0; }
    test -c /dev/null || { stop; exit 0; }

end script

exec /usr/sbin/dibbler-client start 2>&1 > /dev/null
```

The problem is that dibbler is obviously started too soon since i'm getting  `Client Critical  Interface eth0/2 is down or doesn't have any link-local address.`
Is there a simple way of solving this with events or i'd have to do it in the `pre-start` ?
I'm using only /etc/networking/interfaces and the networking script for configuration. So no network manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem was that the ipv6 wasn't started even though the interface was up.

Doing some browsing there was a suggestion to start the ipv6 module right during boot by editing the `/etc/modules` .

Another solution is supposedly to enable the `inactive-mode` in the dibbler configuration `/etc/dibbler/client.conf`

I wanted to do it purely in upstart script so here's the `.conf` file that I tested and seems to be working:

```
# dibbler-client
#
# The dibbler dhcpv6 client

description     "dibbler-client"

start on (started network-interface
          or started network-manager
          or started networking)
stop on runlevel [!2345]

pre-start script
    test -x /usr/sbin/dibbler-client || { stop; exit 0; }
    test -c /dev/null || { stop; exit 0; }

    TIMEOUT=50 #5 second timeout - eatch iteration sleeps for 1/10th of a second
    LOG_FILE=/tmp/dibbler_upstart.log

    until [ $TIMEOUT -eq 0 ]; do
        if ip addr show dev eth0 | grep -e 'inet6.*link.$'; then
                echo "Detected inet6 link-local, exiting" >> $LOG_FILE
                ip addr show dev eth0 >> $LOG_FILE
                exit 0;
        fi
        TIMEOUT=$((TIMEOUT-1))
        sleep .1
    done

    echo "Timeout waiting for IP address" >> $LOG_FILE
    exit 1;

end script

exec /usr/sbin/dibbler-client start 2>&1 > /dev/null
```

If someone knows how to detect ipv6 status with events that would be a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 1):

Your job runs when the interface comes up, but it's not yet configured. This job carries the NetworkManager. And NetworkManager does not emit upstart events. That's the problem.

I think the cleanest way would be **a dispatcher script for NetworkManager**.

Create a file in `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/` with the following contents:

```
#!/bin/bash
# NetworkManager sets those parameters
INTERFACE=$1
ACTION=$2

if [ "$INTERFACE" == "eth0" ] && [ "$ACTION" == "up" ]; then
  # some tests before starting...
  /usr/sbin/dibbler-client start 2>&1 > /dev/null
elif [ "$INTERFACE" == "eth0" ] && [ "$ACTION" == "down" ]; then
  # maybe stop the client...
fi
```

Comment: I forgot to say im not using network manager as this is a server.. Also dibblers problem is not that the interface has to be configured but rather linklocal address has to exist. This should happen right after interface comes up if ipv6 is enabled.

Comment: NetworkManager emits upstart events through /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/ifupdown.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need the following start on:

```
start on net-device-up IFACE=eth0 ADDRFAM=inet6
```

alternatively, you can use static-network-up to wait for all interfaces to be up.